# Draw circles on the image after applying hough transform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, image-processing, aforge

I'm using HoughCircleTransformation class of AForge to detect circles. I want to draw circles on the image where the circles are detected (to highlight the circles on the original image). How can i modify the 'foreach loop' to do that?

```
 public Bitmap hough(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        HoughCircleTransformation circleTransform = new HoughCircleTransformation(35);
        // apply Hough circle transform
        circleTransform.ProcessImage(bmp);
        Bitmap houghCirlceImage = circleTransform.ToBitmap();
        // get circles using relative intensity
        HoughCircle[] circles = circleTransform.GetCirclesByRelativeIntensity(0.5);
        int numCircles = circleTransform.CirclesCount;
        MessageBox.Show("Number of circles found : " + numCircles.ToString());
        foreach (HoughCircle circle in circles)
        {

          //code to draw circle
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have X,Y and radius.

To draw on Bitmap use System.Drawing.Graphics.

e.g.

```
  var g = Graphics.FromBitmap(bmp); 
  g.DrawEllipse(...);
```